# Why is my RTC DS1307 not being recognized?

Tags: raspbian, i2c, rtc, ds1307

I'm trying to wire up a DS1307 RTC to my Model B Pi. I'm following the diagram as shown in this crude image [image] and I've also tried it like [this](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FA6/ZKYH/HOW0HPTG/FA6ZKYHHOW0HPTG.pdf)

but it isn't recognized by the Pi. When I run

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

I don't see anything registered. When I wire up a complete RTC I bought on ebay, I see it registered as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Parts used:

- [DS1307+-ND](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&keywords=DS1307%2B-ND) ([datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf))
- [CRYSTAL 32.768KHZ 6PF THRU](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?KeyWords=728-1000-ND&WT.z_header=search_go) ([datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Seiko%20Instruments%20PDFs/VT200F-6PF20PPM.pdf))

Comment: Have you tried the complete circuit with battery and crystal?

Comment: Sorry, I should ahve put that. The crude diagram I put up doesn't show the batt hookup, but i tried it with the full DIP wired up, even trying a few things on the OUT pin.

Comment: Loose wire?  Try swapping SDA/SCL.

Comment: @joan that's what it was. I used a different breadboard and I got it working.

Comment: @DustinDavis A loose wire?

Comment: @joan basically, yeah.